# Migrate power query to SSAS or SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, powerbi, ssas, etl

currently we are having some transformations and data manipulations using the query designer in power bi, so our next move is to automate these manipulations through SSIS, so what's the better approach should we either:

1- Migrate to SSAS then deploy to the analysis services in SSMS, and then import as a source in SSIS.

OR

2-We migrate directly to SSIS using the newly added source component ( Power Query Source ).

Comment: [Dataflows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-dataflows-overview) are another option for your case.

Answer (score 1):

Between these two options, the easiest approach is to  migrate directly to SSIS using the newly added source component, since there is no need to use SSAS in data manipulation while you have access to the main source using Power Query.